# In extractors, does the unapply method need to be in object or could it be in the class?

Tags: scala

In `extractors` in  Scala, the `unapply` method is used for pattern matching. Does the method need to be in defined in an `object` or could I also define it in a `class`? In the following code, I thought of creating an object of D (which will have the `unapply` method) but it didn't compile.

```
scala> class D(val i:Int, val j:Int) {
     | def unapply(d:D) = Some((d.i, d.j))
     | }
defined class D

scala> val d1 = new D(1,2)
d1: D = D@4b22214d

scala> d1 match {
     | case new D((i,j)) => println(s"got ${i}, ${j}") //will not compile
     | case _ => println("no D")
     | }
```

But if I create a companion object, pattern matching works

```
object D {
def unapply(d:D) = Some((d.i, d.j))
}

defined object D

scala> val d = new D(1,2)
d: D = D@42a7e7e1

scala> d match {
     | case D(1,2) =>println("d with 1,2")
     | case _ => println("something else")
     | }
d with 1,2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the specification (section §8.1.8)](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/08-pattern-matching.html#8.1.8):

> ### Extractor Patterns
>
> An extractor pattern `x(p1,…,pn)` where `n ≥ 0` is of the same
>   syntactic form as a constructor pattern. However, instead of a case
>   class, the stable identifier x **denotes an object** which has a member
>   method named  unapply or unapplySeq that matches the pattern.

<s>Thus, the extractor must be part of the object definition.</s>

As @sepp2k points out, it is not nessacery for x to be defined as an object definition, it is sufficient that x will provide an instance method named unapply. As he showed in the example:

```
class Sub(x: Int) {
  def unapply(y: Int) = Some(y-x)
}

object Main extends App {
  val Sub23 = new Sub(23)
  42 match {
    case Sub23(i) => println(i) // Prints 42 - 23
  }
}
```

Comment: Just because `x` needs to be an object, that doesn't mean that it needs to be defined with an `object` definition. You can define a class with an unapply method and then define `val x = TheClass(arguments)`.

Comment: @sepp2k That would be an apply, wouldn't it? Would the specification say object when it really means a template?

Comment: "That would he an apply, wouldn't it?" If I do `val x = TheClass(arguments)` and then `something match { case x(p1, ..., pn) => ...}`, that will call `x.unapply`, not `x.apply`. "Would the specification say object when it really means a template?" I don't know what you mean by "template" here, but I can tell you for a fact that what I said works fine.

Comment: @sepp2k If you `x match { case  TheClass(y) => }` then that's an unapply. Perhaps I've misinterpreted the meaning in the spec.

Comment: `x match ...` changes things around completely. In the spec `x` is the pattern, not the the thing we're matching on. So we're talking about `unnamedObject match { case x(p1, ..., pn) => ... }`. And in that case I'm saying that `x` does not have to be defined via `object` - it can be defined using `val x = ...`. All that matters is that it has an `unapply` method.

Comment: Perhaps a concrete example makes things clearer: https://ideone.com/60RNlR Here `Sub23` is an object that has an `unapply` method and that's why I can use it as a pattern. The fact that it's been created by instantiating the `Sub` class and not via an `object` definition does not matter.

Comment: @sepp2k Ok, I see what you mean. Given that Sub as an instance value has an unapply is sufficient.